# How do I catch errors using Zeep and Python 3.7

Tags: python, zeep

I am learning how to use Zeep as my soap client. I am able to connect to a WSDL and view services, however, I am stuck on how to catch all possible exceptions. I am only able to catch KeyError. I want to be able to catch a few more:

Basically something similar to the below http client example:

except (http.client.HTTPException, ValueError, KeyError, AttributeError) as e

I would want to use try.....except

```
try:
    session = Session()
    session.auth = HttpNtlmAuth(username, password)

    request_data = {
    }
    client = Client(wsdl, transport=Transport(session=session))
    response = client.service.GetPendingBills(**request_data)
    billobj = json.loads(response)
    print(billobj)
    bills = (len(billobj["Bills"]))
except KeyError as e:
    bills = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is too late, but you can import zeep.exceptions and handle all kinds of exceptions that you have that way. You just need to check the exception and catch it as you have demonstrated above.

Solution is shown [in this documentation](https://github.com/mvantellingen/python-zeep/issues/392)

Answer (score 0):

I decided to import requests and handle the exceptions as indicated below:

except (requests.exceptions.HTTPError, KeyError, TimeoutError) as e

Thanks